# Missing edit permissions on a kubernetes cluster on GCP

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform

This is a Google Cloud specific problem.
I returned from vacation and noticed I can no longer manage workloads or cluster due to this error: "Missing edit permissions on account"

[image]

[image]

I am a sole person with access to this account (owner role) and yet I see this issue.
The troubleshooting [guide](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/troubleshooting?&_ga=2.209122386.-1512594765.1552850111#gke_service_account_deleted) suggests checking system service account role, looks like it's set up correctly (why would it not if I haven't edited it):
[image]
If it's not set up correctly it suggests turning off/on the Kubernetes API on GCP, but when you press on "disable" there's a scary-looking prompt that your Kubernetes resources are going to be deleted, so obviously I can't do that.

Upon trying to connect to it I get

```
gcloud container clusters get-credentials cluster-1 --zone us-west1-b --project PROJECT_ID
Fetching cluster endpoint and auth data.
WARNING: cluster cluster-1 is not running. The kubernetes API may not be available.
```

In the logs I found a record (the last one) that is 4 days old:

> "Readiness probe failed: Get http://10.20.0.5:44135/readiness: net/http: request canceled (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)"

Anyone here has any ideas?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is solved,
I had to upgrade node versions in the pool.
What a misleading error message.
Hopefully, this helps someone.